# Google Cloud Composer - Unknown hook type "sftp"

Tags: airflow, sftp, google-cloud-composer

Trying to add SFTP connection to Apache Airflow run on the Composer.
Here is some packages' listing;

| package-name | version |
| --- | --- |
| apache-airflow | 2.2.5+composer |
| apache-airflow-providers-ftp | 3.2.0 |
| apache-airflow-providers-google | 2022.10.17+composer |
| apache-airflow-providers-sftp | 4.1.0 |
| apache-airflow-providers-ssh | 3.2.0 |
| paramiko | 2.12.0 |
| sshtunnel | 0.4.0 |

This is the message I get when hitting the Test button:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Cloud Composer are you using? Is it `Cloud Composer 1` or `Cloud Composer 2`? https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview

Comment: @Scott B, This is Composer 1.20.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior on `Composer 1` because in `Composer 1` if **DAG serialization** is on, the **Airflow webserver** is using a base image that **doesn’t include customer installed pypi packages**.

Therefore, this functionality doesn’t work properly.

You may upgrade to `Composer 2` so that everything will work properly.

However, if you want to stay on `Composer 1`, you  may try changing the `conn_type` from ‘sftp’ to ‘ftp’.